# How can I edit my comment?

Tags: support, comments

How can I edit my comment? The edit button disappeared. I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: "This extra sentences are need to make a quality question": if you mean you want to add some information, **don't use a comment for that**. You can edit your question instead.

Comment: Potential close voters: It is all right if you can find a duplicate, but this issue most definitely can be reproduced. (I, for one, run into it every other day!)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can only edit your comment for a short while (5 minutes) after posting it. You did nothing wrong as the system is performing as designed.

There is no hassle with deleting your old comment and rewriting a new one with the additional information you wish to include.

To delete a comment, just hover over your comment and you'll see 'Delete' button for deletion.

Comment: If you delete comment and write a new one, then you can not follow the discussion. Sometimes it's very useful to edit your comment (grammatical errors and so on).

Comment: Now when you hover to you comments, you'll see the `Delete` button.

Comment: To clarify what @Rekshino said, if you delete a comment and repost it (corrected) after there have been subsequent comments, it will scramble the dialogue. If the system is working as designed, perhaps the system's design could be reconsidered.